# Heroku re-install "Directory not empty" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple rails app that runs (localhost:3000) when `rails server` is launched, but refuses to run when `heroku open` is launched. I have attempted various fixes following different pointers here (and elsewhere) and repeatedly updated and installed bundler. Today, when I tried `heroku open`, I got this:

`Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com`.

So I did (even though I thought Heroku CLI had been installed). Weird thing is: I couldn't find the installed Heroku CLI app on my computer. To make sure Heroku CLI had been installed properly, I tried

`brew install heroku/brew/heroku`

as instructed on Heroku's website. Sure enough, I got this message:

`Warning: heroku/brew/heroku 7.7.8 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 7.7.8, run 'brew reinstall heroku'`

When I tried `brew reinstall heroku`, I got this message:

```
Error: The brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/heroku
Target /usr/local/bin/heroku
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/heroku'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite heroku

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run heroku

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/heroku -> /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku

....

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8: 17,135 files, 45.5MB, built in 1 minute 9 seconds
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8.reinstall
```

What does this even mean? Should I do it without messing up other apps? I am just beginning to understand there are differences among local/global/root installations, so could use some help figuring out this one. Thanks in advance!